# Jade is not loading block

Tags: templates, express, pug

I have an views/layout.jade file:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app='movieseat')
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
    block footer
```

In this layout I declare a block content & block footer. In the same views folder I have index.jade & footer.jade files:

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title} user! Peter Boomsma
```

And footer.jade:

```
extends layout

block footer
    p Footer
    script(src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js")
    script(src="javascripts/minified.jsconcat.js")
```

When I visit my localhost the layout.jade is loaded and I see the content of the content block but I don't see the content of the footer block.

In my app.js I have:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
```

And in my routes folder I have an index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

What am I overlooking? Why does the layout.jade show the block content but not the block footer?

Comment: It seems to me that `footer` should be part of the layout, or just a regular [include](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/). The `index.jade` file supplies the `content` block, but not the `footer` block, which is why it's not being rendered.

Comment: So when the page is loaded the router renders the index, and index extends to layout so the layout is being loaded.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works.